Conduction of Thyristor and Diode
Consider the following circuit:

Let \$ \phi \$ denote the angle for which the thyristor T1 is triggered, i want to know why when \$ \omega t = \theta \in (0, \phi) \$ T2 and D2 are conducting i see that in that interval, the point B has negative polarity but that doesnt explain that T2 should conduct.
Here is how I think of the circuit in that particular interval : \$ v_c (\theta) = V_{C} - V_{A'} = V_{C}-V_B - V_{A'} + V_B = V_{T_2} - V_{D_2} = Ri + L di + E\$
My brain stopped at this stage, after which I went to PSIM to simulate this circuit as the following:

With the source being of RMS magnitude 45 V and 50 Hz  frequency, I omitted the DC voltage at the load for simplicity purposes, the resistance is of 12 Ω and the inductance of 0.1 H
I get this graph of the voltage at each probe:


I cannot parse this.  What is interval B?  What values are assigned to L, R, E?  What is the amplitude of v(θ)?

Can you show what you mean with a figure (with values)?

@FabioBarone the problem is that the professor provided this circuitry with no values just general abstract model, v(θ) = A sin(θ)

What is A', is that the ground or 0V node of your circuit?

I have no idea what it is A', i just denoted it as a node, i thought ground could be chosen by us no? as a reference point @FabioBarone

Your simulator, PSIM, should have a node that it considers as being at zero volts, so the waveforms of voltages are with respect to that node.  That is a special node to all simulators, and is usually given the identity of "node 0".  Some simulators, like LTspice, will abort and exit with an error if you try to run a simulation without defining which node is GND.

so if i set A' as ground , it wouldnt change anything? the pair of diode/thyristor in the starting interval would still act as a freewheel diode? @FabioBarone

Provided only one node is set as gnd, then yes, this won't change how the circuit behaves.  Before setting A' as gnd, check to see if your simulator has already allocated a node to gnd.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

You should not see points A, B and C. It is "better" to see the v(B)-v(C), v(A)-v(B) and v(C)-v(A) ... with currents.

Made with microcap v12
For a mixed SCR-diodes bridge, we can have some waveforms like these ...
Note that E is positive (= 50 V).

And for currents

Here are the two oscillograms for E= -50 V ...
Note that currents are greater. The load was "reduced" by making R4= 12.5 Ohm.


UPDATE:
For a SCR full bridge, the waveforms are somewhat different.
NB: a constant current is used in the load ...
For a firing angle of 0.002 ms ... The power is "positive" in the load ...

For a firing angle of 0.008 ms ... The power is "negative" in the load ...


But i want to know why such waveforms are like that, thats the problem hahah

To know the "waveforms", you must first "try" to see what is the "voltage" across the SCR. If positive, you can fire it. And when it is fired, you must know until it is OFF. For that, knowing the voltage is important ... and how is going the current towards zero. Note that when the load is really "inductive", you can make the "approximation" that the current across the load is "constant", which is done in some study and make the "searching" ... easy.

merci beaucoup !

No worries. It is always a pleasure. Good luck.

Short answer: negative polarity of voltage v(θ) is indeed possible while T2 is conducting.  It depends on the current flowing in the DC side, through R - L - E (marked as i(θ) on your drawing).  Whether a thyristor continues to stay on depends on the current passing through it, and not some other voltage somewhere else.
Longer answer: not possible unless you improve your question.
